# Check if string in the exact form of “<int1>,<int2>” in Python, without using regex, or try/catch

Tags: python, string

I'm converting a string of two integers into a tuple. I need to make sure my string is formatted exactly in the form of:

```
"<int1>,<int2>"
```

This is not a duplicate to an earlier question. Since that did not address restrictions I did not know about earlier. My parameter will be "4,5" for example. I'm not allowed to write other helper functions to check if they are formatted correctly. The checks must be done in a single function called convert_to_tuple

I just looked at the project specs again, and I'm not allowed to import any new modules, so regex is off the table. I'm also not allowed to use try/catch either.

Can you point me in the write direction? Thanks

Here is my code for converting the string into a tuple. So I need some type of check for executing this code.

```
if foo: 
s1 = "12,24"
string_li = s1.split(',')
num_li = [int(x) for x in string_li]
num_tuple = tuple(num_li)
return num_tuple

else:
empty_tuple = ()
return empty_tuple
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: It will throw an exception if `x` in the list comprehension is not convertible to an `int`

Comment: Add all the checks you need. Eg. `num_tuple = tuple([int(x) for x in string_li if any(x) and len(string_li) == 2 and s1.count(",") == 1 and string_li[0].isdigit() and string_li[1].isdigit()])` Probably lots of redundancies in htere but it should give you a few examples of checks/tests to use

Comment: The "duplicate" is not a duplicate, since it lacks the same restrictions (it doesn't rule out exceptions or regexes).

Comment: Does "1,-2" count? What about "0xa,0xb"?

Comment: And what about "01,23"? Do you want leading zeroes to be flagged as an error or ignored?

Comment: The "duplicate" is very much a duplicate since it was asked by the same person.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie to stackoverflow. How to I delete my older question. How to fix my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? (Edited to meet OP's requirements)

```
def is_int(string):
    return string and set(string).issubset(set('1234567890'))

def check_str(s):
    parts = s.split(',', 1)
    return len(parts) == 2 and is_int(parts[0]) and is_int(parts[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for testing (without converting, and without regexes or exception handling) a simple:

```
vals = s1.split(',')
if len(vals) == 2 and all(map(str.isdigit, vals)):
```

would verify that there are two components and both of them are non-empty and composed solely of digits.

Comment: Would this check if there is a comma as indicated by s1?

Comment: @ixbo45: That's what the `split` and `len` check are for. To verify it has exactly one comma.